# Getting no configuration error when running Storybook in a turbo repo

Tags: storybook, turborepo

I am running turbo repo with and my ui library has storybook. When I execute "start-storybook -p 6006", I get this error:

> ERR! Error: No configuration files have been found in your configDir...
> Storybook needs either a "main" or "config" file.

I get this error even if I have main.js in my .storybook directory. I am not sure what's causing this issue.